# Regex cannot accept two numbers followed c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression pattern in C#. The only restriction is pattern can not accept two numbers followed. For example:

- q1w2e3r4 -> OK
- Q1$2e3r4 -> OK
- q1w2e33r -> not accepted
- Q14we3r4 -> not accepted

And I just don't know how can regular expression could be. I have tried with

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?=.*\\d{2})");
```

but it is not working.

Help please, thanks.

Comment: How about simply `\d{2}`?

Comment: Using `\d{2}`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/P2KQvB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this pattern

```
^(?!.*[0-9]{2}).*
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/12)

Answer (score 1):

Regexs are not really designed to test for negative conditions.  A better approach is to match on `\d{2}` and only execute your code when the regex **doesn't** match the string.